# padding-right for display:inline elements in IE6

Tags: css, internet-explorer-6

In IE6, display:block with a colored background color extends that color to the far right side of the page.  Changing to display:inline fixes that problem, but the color now ends immediately after my last character, despite the fact that I have specified padding-right: 1em
in the CSS.  padding-left is working, but not padding-right.  Any workarounds? I have been googling for hours and cannot find an answer.

Comment: Can you post some code that reproduces the problem?

Comment: In trying to do so, I am now seeing correct behavior in IE6 with my simple example.
<html>
<head>
<style type="text/css">
div
{
background-color:yellow;
}
.padding
{
display: inline;
    line-height:25px;
    height:25px;
padding-top:12px;
padding-bottom:13px;
padding-right:50px;
padding-left:50px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<div class="padding">This is a paragraph with specified paddings.</div>
</body>

</html>

So I guess there is some other CSS in my team's larger environment that is mucking it up. Sorry for what might be a false alarm.

Comment: Firebug could be useful in seeing where any extra styles are coming from, even though your problem is specific to IE 6.

Comment: For IE6 you could use the Internet Explorer Developer Toolbar from Microsoft. http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=e59c3964-672d-4511-bb3e-2d5e1db91038&displaylang=en It's like Firebug (sort of) but for IE6.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would hope `display:block` and `display:inline` work that way in other browsers too, not just IE6, since that's how they're meant to work. Block elements take up the full width (unless you specify a width yourself, in which case it will be that width) and have a newline afterwards, whereas inline only takes up the width it needs (even if you give it a different width, it won't use it) and has no new line. This is why the background colour extends to the far right of the page when it's a block element.

Padding should work fine on an inline element, so it's possible you have another element or style which is conflicting and causing the issue. Without seeing a code sample it's impossible to tell.

You could try using `display:inline-block` will keep the element inline (so that it doesn't take up a full line and have a line break) but it will behave as a block element with regards to padding, margins and widths.

Note though that IE6 (and 7) only allow `display:inline-block` on elements that are default inline elements (`span`, etc)

Failing that, you would need to provide a code example that reproduces the problem so we can see if something else is having an impact.

Comment: display:block respects the width property, though, and that can be used to limit the rightward extent. display-inline does not. You might be correct that all the other browsers are wrong and IE6 is correct.  I would just like to know how to cause IE6 to render as I am hoping I can. Thanks for answering though.

Comment: Ah sorry, I didn't mean blocks should always take up the full width, only when you don't specify a width yourself. If you specify a width yourself, then block elements will obviously be that width, whereas inline will always just use what they need and won't change width, even if you specify a width for them. I've updated that bit in my answer to make it clearer. Although I may have just made it more confusing :)

Answer (score 1):

Try setting the element to display:inline-block. That sometimes helps.

Also... seeing the code in context would make it easier to see what's going on.

Comment: Nope.  Renders just like display: block.  Thanks anyhow.

Answer (score 0):

The best solution is to ignore IE 6. People still using IE 6 are used to getting bad web page displays and they are mostly using IE 6 because their network administrators think it is safer to let everybody use it.

As for a second choice solution: pad a hard space (`&nbsp;`) after the text.

Comment: I disagree. You need to analyse your traffic profile (in Google Analytics or elsewhere) to see how important IE6 is for your business.

Comment: I can't ignore IE6; the product has to work on IE6 and above, plus all the good browsers. The text itself is not in a place where I can add an nbsp only when I need it.   Thanks.

Comment: I disagree as well. IE6 is still an important factor, whether we like it or not.